# Should I put a www-site on my CV?

Tags: resume

I made a website whilst working within a team. However, when the project was almost finished, the boss decided to fire me out as they managed to finish it without me. Now, the page HTML-source has the following line

```
<meta name="author" content="My collegue's name" />
```

but there is no mention that I took part in the project. So I can prove that I worked in the project by showing my reference but if an employer checks the page source before he or she has seen my reference, he or she might think I am a cheater. So how to mention that kind of situation in my CV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put in the work, then you have every right to mention that you did the work. As long as you can discuss the design choices and trade-offs that you made, the design requirements that led to a non-negotiable implementation of specific features and you can describe what your code (not necessarily accessible) was supposed to do, then you should be in the clear.

None of us can prove every last thing we did, so we have to settle for the next best option, which is us coming across as credible with respect to our claims.

Comment: +1. In addition, the fact that one person has their name in the source doesn't mean it's not a collaborative work.